# Crontab fails to run my Perl module

Tags: linux, perl, cron

My perl module is working fine when whenever I run it without using crontab,
but when I try running the script through Crontab it's throwing some error like couldnt find other modules which have been called inside my Perl.pl file.

The line I have added in Crontab file is

```
* * * * * cd /usr/bin/perl | perl path_to_script/script.pl;
```

The error I am getting is

```
Can't locate module.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /home/path/lib /usr/another/path/lib /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 .) at path_to_script/script.pl line 23
```

When ever I am tring to run the script through crontab file it fails to connect to the sub modules.

Comment: Please post your cronjob line. Have you checked if you are using full paths?

Comment: **Please don't paraphrase errors**.  Paste the **exact** error into the body of your message.

Comment: The error `cd perl | perl` is kind of amusing, but I think harmless. The usual command separator is a semicolon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
*/5 * * * *        bash -l  perl  path/script.pl
# change the above to your crontab settings
```

Answer (score 3):

So many things can be different when running from crontab. Such as:

- different user
- different shell

Often the `$PATH` under crontab is not what you usually expect it to be. You may have to explicitly provide the `$PERL5LIB` environment variable so a Perl script knows what library folders to look in.

Comment: Can you explain with a example how to specify about $PATH and $PERL5LIB?

Comment: The Exact Error I am getting is "Can't locate script.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /home/path/lib /usr/another/path/lib /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 .) at path_to_script/script.pl" Whenever i m tring to run the file through crontab it fails to connect to the modules it is calling inside.

Answer (score 0):

Run Perl with an -I (uppercase i) option indicating where to find the missing module(s), or create a wrapper something like

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /usr/lib/perl
PERL5LIB=$HOME/lib/perl perl path_to_script/script.pl
```

... and run this script from your crontab instead.

(The value of `PERL5LIB` might have to be more complex than this; maybe copy/paste from its value in your interactive shell.)

Answer (score 0):

Just add the `PERL5LIB` environment variable in `/etc/crontab` and include the path to the `.pm` module file.

Example:

```
PERL5LIB=/root/perl5/lib/perl5:/usr/share/perl5
```